# How can I fix this "Error using vertcat: Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent" in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, error-handling, concatenation

I am writing two different pieces of code – the first creates a function "rotateAboutX" that returns a rotation matrix that rotates by an angle about x. The second uses that function to create that matrix. My error is as follows:

Error using vertcat: Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in rotateAboutX (line 2): Rx = [1 0 0;

```
function Rx = rotateAboutX(angle)
Rx = [1 0 0;
      0 cos(angle) -sin(angle);
      0 sin(angle) cos(angle)];
end
```

```
M = [0;
     0;
     1];

t_sec_RF = 0:0.0001:1;
flip = 0.0001 * t_sec_RF;

for iRep = 1:8
     Rx = rotateAboutX(flip / 360 * 2 * pi);
     flipMat = Rx * M;
     ...
end
```

This function worked in a previous area of the code which is why I am stumped on this error. If anybody can lead me in the right direction with what my mistake is, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `t_sec_RF` is a vector, so the `angle` argument passed to your function is a vector. What do you think the function should return in this case?

Comment: Use the debugger, stop at the line that produces the error, and look at what each of the components you’re concatenating are. Notice they are sizes you didn’t expect, then work backwards from there to find out why those sizes are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The output argument was expected to be a 3x3 matrix, but your input argument "flip / 360 * 2 * pi" is a vector, so "cos(angle)" in the function space is also a vector, then the output matrix cannot be created.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much!